# phpunit not recognising use of count()

Tags: php, interface, count, mocking, phpunit

I have a PHP object which implements the built-in Countable interface. I am then mocking this object for a unit test:

```
    $mapper = $this->getMockBuilder("Search_Model_Mapper_Search")
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array("find", "count"))
        ->getMock();
    $mapper->expects($this->once())
        ->method("find")
        ->with(array("body" => "kajsgfkblkjasfgdjkb"))
        ->will($this->returnValue($mapper));
    $mapper->expects($this->once())
        ->method("count")
        ->will($this->returnValue(0));
```

And the section of code being tested reads as:

```
    $results = $this->getMapper("fulltext")->find(array("body" => $requestParams['q']));
    if (count($results) === 0) {
        $this->view->messages[] = "Sorry, no results were found. Please check your search terms and try again";
        return; 
    }
```

PHPUnit 4.0.17 is not recognising the use of count() - I have to use `$results->count()` for the assertion to be met.

PHPUnit 3.4 did not have this problem.

I can't find anything to help figure out this problem in the PHPUnit documentation - is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I have been over-relying on autoload behaviour in the Zend implementation of PHPUnit, and fell foul of a change in PHPUnit's mock objects.

In this specific case, the class being mocked wasn't being autoloaded due to limits in Zend/PHPUnit and autoloading (the test is not bootstrapping the whole application - nor should it, since this supposed to be a unit test) - this used to cause a "class not found" error in PHPUnit 3.4, but the new PHPUnit 4.x implementation will fabricate a stub class. The stub class did not implement any interfaces, so the PHP count() built-in did not know the object was Countable.

I've now required the specific source file for the class being mocked, and the mock (and PHP count() built-in) is behaving exactly as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Count is an internal function of PHP and not mocked in your scenario.  You mocked the getMapper() call to count (`getMapper->Count()`). For your test, simply mock the `$this->getMapper("fulltext")->find()` and have that return nothing, so the PHP count() will equal 0.

Comment: PHPs built-in count function should be calling the mocked count method (as it does in phpunit 3.4) because the mocked class is implementing Countable.

Comment: If you simply use 'any' in the mock for all methods, does that help  in case there is a structure change in PHPUnit and its implementation?  Not sure otherwise.